# Beta Function : Proof

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

Prove that

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{x^{p-1} + x^{q-1}}{(1 + x)^{p+q}} dx = \beta (p,q)$$

Please help !

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal My edit $\mathrm{Beta}(p,q)$ concerning the Beta function notation was wrong indeed. I will not edit this post further, but $\beta(p,q)$ should be changed to $\mathrm{B}(p,q)$: "its symbol Β is a *Greek capital* β rather than the similar Latin capital B" -- [Wikipedia entry Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{1}{y}$ or $x=\frac{y}{y+1}$ and consider the Euler function.

Comment: I can prove Beta(p,q) = integration of y^p-1/(1+y)^p+q dy with limit from 0 to infinity.But,what after that ?